# Why Does the following c# not return 957? (it returns 0)

Tags: c#

I'm baffled on the tiny piece of code below that fails to return 957 as I would expect. I'm kind of embarrassed to post but I can't see the problem.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertToInteger("957.13"));
        }

        private static string ConvertToInteger(string timeStartIn)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(timeStartIn, out var timeStart);

            return timeStart.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because `957.13` is not an integer.

Comment: You could have checked the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

Comment: Keep in mind that `TryParse` will return false if the conversion fails.

Answer (score 4):

You should check [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method help.
It says:

> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or **zero if the conversion failed**.

Since `957.13` is a string representing a decimal value, TryParse method returns 0 because a decimal number is not an integer one.

Comment: My goof. I had thought it did a truncate. So I guess this is best.  Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(timeStartIn)));

Comment: No need for all that.  Just parse it to a decimal or float, then *cast* it to an integer.  Or use `Convert.ToInt32`.  There's no need to truncate manually.  e.g. `(int)float.Parse(timeStartIn)`

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a float or a decimal type, use a floor or ceiling function then you can convert it to a full number integer.  You could also convert it to a string and split it by the decimal point, then use only the first segment and convert that to a full number integer.

NOTE: The string method does not take rounding into account.